# GDB stack output not showing full hex address?

Tags: c, debugging, gdb

my GDB output for the stack looks like this

```
0xffffd688:     0x98    0xd6    0xff    0xff    0x75    0x84    0x04    0x08
```

I'd like it to look more like this

```
0xbffff3b0: 0xbffff620 0xbffff3c9 0×00000006 0xbffff3d8
```

is there an option? am I missing something trivial here?

Comment: try `x/4xw $esp` perhaps?

Comment: Can you provide more information - what command, what OS etc?

Answer (score 1):

You indeed want `(gdb) x/4xw $sp`:

```
(gdb) help x
Examine memory: x/FMT ADDRESS.
ADDRESS is an expression for the memory address to examine.
FMT is a repeat count followed by a format letter and a size letter.
Format letters are o(octal), x(hex), d(decimal), u(unsigned decimal),
  t(binary), f(float), a(address), i(instruction), c(char) and s(string).
Size letters are b(byte), h(halfword), w(word), g(giant, 8 bytes).
The specified number of objects of the specified size are printed
according to the format.
```

In this case, the **repeat count** is `4`, the **format letter** is `x`(hex) and the **size letter** is `w`(word, 4 bytes).